# How to copy an object state into another object partially in java

Tags: java, object, cloning

i want to copy one object state into another object as partially.

**Class**

```
public class Fruit {

    private String name;
    private String price;
    private String taste;

    public Fruit()
    {

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String getTaste() {
        return taste;
    }
    public void setTaste(String taste) {
        this.taste = taste;
    }

}

main()
{
Fruit fruit1=new Fruit();
fruit1.setPrice("50");
fruit1.setTaste("sweet");
Fruit fruit2=new Fruit();
fruit2.setName("Apple");
// i want to copy price and taste property values to same properties of fruit2 object like update how do i do that
}
```

i want to only copy price and taste properties to fruit 2

i want to copy part of the state to another object without affecting its state

how do i do that please let me know correct way to do that?

Comment: `fruit2.setName(fruit1.getName()); fruit2.setPrice(fruit1.getPrice());` ??

Comment: Just use your setters and getters from that class.

Comment: it's just an example  i want to do that to mass amount of object

Comment: it's not about Fruit class i want an general way to copy an object state into another one partially

Comment: Then show your code for your real problem and explain in detail what went wrong. Create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

The Fruit Class has to Implement Cloneable interface available in java.lang package and provide the methode clone in fruit class.

Now in main class, use fruit2=(Fruit)fruit1.clone();
and try to print the price and taste.

Comment: This seems to be pretty off the target. Cloning will create a new instance with the complete state of the given object. The OP is looking to copy *part* of the state to *another existing object*.